# "Unable to find image" when sharing using Instagram

Tags: android, android-intent, instagram

in my application the user has the option to share an image on Instagram.
This is the code i'm using :

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");

        final ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
        final String[] p1 = new String[]{MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns._ID, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.TITLE, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATE_TAKEN};
        Cursor c1 = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null, null, p1[1] + " DESC");


        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoUri);
        shareIntent.setPackage("com.instagram.android");

        c1.close();
        startActivity(shareIntent);
```

The problem is that it shows a message on the app saying

> Unable to load image.

I added this permission in my manifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

i also made sure to give permission from my device but nothing is working.

Answer (score 2):

i solved my problem. i removed this line of code

```
        Cursor c1 = cr.query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, p1, null, null, p1[1] + " DESC");
```

and i replaced this

```
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, photoUri);
```

with this

```
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), photoPath, "img", "Identified image")));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
String type = "image/*";
String filename = "/myPhoto.jpg";
String mediaPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + filename;

createInstagramIntent(type, mediaPath);

private void createInstagramIntent(String type, String mediaPath){

    // Create the new Intent using the 'Send' action.
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);

    // Set the MIME type
    share.setType(type);

    // Create the URI from the media
    File media = new File(mediaPath);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(media);

    // Add the URI to the Intent.
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);

    // Broadcast the Intent.
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share to"));
}
```

supported Photo Format  are jpeg, gif, png

Comment: this only open a "share" menu for me. i added the .jpg to my code and still it's not working